# Remove focus and click event - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day.

Create 5 divs dynamically with jQuery. These Divs are created after I type in a text type Input.

After creating these divs have to click on one of them and pick up the text, and add this text in the input that entered the text.

But the problem that when I type the text the first time, I give a FOCUS on input, so when I click on any div created by me, the following happens:
1 - The first click, remove the FOCUS
2 - In the second click it sends the value to the input

You see I have to give 2 clicks, but I like to do that in just one click ...

```
$('.tags_add').on("click",".tags_vdd", function(){
    //$("input[name=tags]").trigger("blur");
    //$(".tags_vdd").trigger("click");
    Pegar_dado = $(this).text();
    $('input[name=tags]').val(Pegar_dado);
});

<div class="tags_add">
   <span class="tags_vdd">ccc</span>
   <span class="tags_vdd">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</span>
   <span class="tags_vdd">cxcc</span>
   <span class="tags_vdd">cc</span>
   <span class="tags_vdd">cxc</span>
</div>

<input type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tags valid"/>
```

Comment: code shown works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/9juc0a0r/ Please provide demo that replicates problem of 2 clicks

Comment: Got my mistake ... I was delegating the focusOut in another event, after removing worked properly ...

`$ ('input [name = tags]'). on ("keydown keypress keyup focusOut", function () {`

Removed the focusOut ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9ttysh7/1/)

After loading the page, I type something in the input, then I select a div and in one click it

```
$('.tags_add').on("click",".tags_vdd", function(){
    Pegar_dado = $(this).text();
    $('input[name=tags]').val(Pegar_dado);
});
```